# How to call angular/cli commands from node?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular-universal, platform-server

Background: I will be building 40+ locales of an applications and pre-rending all the pages to static html.

To do this I need access to every `AppServerModuleNgFactory`.

### **Questions:**

1- Can I call ng build from from `@angular/cli` package in a file called `build.ts` w/o using node `exec`?

**From this:**

```
exec(ng build --output-path=dist/apps/portfolio/fr-CA -prod --aot --bh=/fr-CA/ --app=portfolio --i18n-file=./apps/portfolio/i18n/messages.fr-CA.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=fr-CA;)

const { AppServerModuleNgFactory} = require('dist/apps/portfolio-server/fr-CA/main.bundle.js');
```

**to *something better* like this:**

```
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory} = await ng.build(`
  -prod
  --aot
  --bh=/fr-CA/
  --app=portfolio
  --i18n-file=./apps/portfolio/i18n/messages.fr-CA.xlf
  --i18n-format=xlf
  --locale=fr-CA`);
```

Comment: It's certainly possible, see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/bin/ng . Though it relies on package internals and doesn't really make the things easier. You still have to deal with streams. I guess that `exec` is the preferable way.

Comment: Bleh I can read like zero percent of this

Comment: This https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/bin/ng#L194-L200

Comment: Both links are broken. Update?

Comment: @ArmeenHarwood did you find any solution ?